# Is there a way to keep Word using VBA on top of UFT while is running?

Tags: vba, ms-word, hp-uft

I need to keep MS WORD on top of the applications, in this case HP UFT for my code to work properly, I don't know why, but this is the only way the macro I created does what it is supposed to.

I created a function that calls the creation of a macro and fills the Word Document with the data sent in the call to the function, but this data is kept only when the Document is being shown, if the document is in the background the data goes away for some reason I don't know yet.

I tried with some properties for the Application like :

```
   Application.Visible = True 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

But none of them worked, is this possible to achieve with UFT?

Comment: code provided seems to be not enough to answer your question, thus try to split your questions into parts, and describe details.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56361871/edit) to include more information.  I suspect that attacking the "data goes away" problem first may remove the need to worry about whether Word is on top.

Comment: @cxw For some reason, the data set in the fields of the macro created in the Word document, gets deleted if the winword.exe application is not being displayed, thats what I meant.

Comment: Are you using `ActiveDocument` in your code, by any chance?  That changes depending on what is on top.  `Documents("Foo.docx")` does not have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the deletion or removal of the data sent, I had to use the following:

```
Application.Activate()
```

So the focus is on the Word File